# How to extract Tensorflow trained weights from graph.pbtxt to raw data

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have trained a custom neural network with the function:

`tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`

After correct training, it contains the following files:

- checkpoint
- events.out.tfevents.1538489166.ti
- model.ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00002
- model.ckpt-0.index
- model.ckpt-10.data-00000-of-00002
- model.ckpt-10.index eval
- graph.pbtxt
- model.ckpt-0.data-00001-of-00002
- model.ckpt-0.meta
- model.ckpt-10.data-00001-of-00002
- model.ckpt-10.meta

Now I need to export the *weights* and *biases* of every layer, into a raw data structure, e.g. an array, `numpy`.

I have read multiple pages on TensorFlow, and on other topics, but neither can find this question. The first thing I would assume to put the fils together into `graph.pd` with the freeze.py as suggested here:

[Tensorflow: How to convert .meta, .data and .index model files into one graph.pb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864363/tensorflow-how-to-convert-meta-data-and-index-model-files-into-one-graph-pb?rq=1)

But then still the main question is unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to evaluate tensors alone, you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow). But if you wish to e.g. deploy your network, you can take a look at TensorFlow [serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/), which is probably the most performant one right now. Or if you want to export this network to other frameworks and use them there, you can actually use [ONNX](https://onnx.ai) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If saving weights and biases in a numpy array is your strict requirement, you can follow this example:

```
# In a TF shell, define all requirements and call the model function 
y = model(x, is_training=False, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE) # For example
```

Once you call this function, you can see all the variables in the graph by running

```
tf.global_variables()
```

You need to restore all these variables from the latest checkpoint (say **ckpt_dir**) and then execute each of these variables to get the latest values.

```
checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./model_dir/')
fine_tune = tf.contrib.slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(checkpoint,
                                                      tf.global_variables(),
                                                      ignore_missing_vars=True)


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
gv = sess.run(tf.global_variables())
```

Now **gv** will be a list of all the values of your variables (weights and biases); You can access any individual component via indexing - **gv[5]** etc. Or you can convert the entire thing into an array and save using numpy.

```
np.save('my_weights', np.array(gv))
```

This will save all your weights and biases in your current working directory as a numpy array - 'my_weights.npy'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer, this partly helps, as the following happens; tf.global_variables() stays empty, which is directly called after tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate. This is probably because of not correctly call the model function y = model(), as im not sure what you mean with that. Furthermore I want to not only save the weights into a numpy array, separate them from each layer.

Comment: Okay. May I ask what exactly do you plan to achieve? And why you can't use checkpoints? Any details on how you're going to use these might also help.