# Tensorflow, change checkpoint model(.meta .index .data) to frozen model(.pd)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

I am not familiar with tensorflow.

I want to transform this network, https://github.com/jiangsutx/SRN-Deblur, from tensorflow to nvidia tensorRT. It need a '.pb' model file, but the project only giving three model files as follow:

- deblur.model-52300.data-00000-of-00001
- deblur.model-52300.index
- deblur.model-52300.meta

**So I want to transform these files to a '.pb' file.**

I have tested the ideas given by:

- https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc
- [Tensorflow: How to convert .meta, .data and .index model files into one graph.pb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864363/tensorflow-how-to-convert-meta-data-and-index-model-files-into-one-graph-pb)

The problem is that both gave ideas are failed because of the **get_checkpoint_state()** and **latest_checkpoint()** giving None value.

Is this caused by the missing of checkpoint file?

Are there other ways to implement this?

Any idea is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from their own repo: they use `get_checkpoint_state` to test a pre-trained model.
https://github.com/jiangsutx/SRN-Deblur/blob/master/models/model.py#L245

So I'd say yes it is because of the missing .ckpt file, not provided by the author.

From experience, usually the first method from metaflow works quite well.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  A chekpoint  is neccessary. And this file gives the model name for .meta .index .data. So I just add a new checkpoint file by myself. And it works well.

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem