# Does "bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph" build Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

What the subject says.

I have a working Tensorflow installation via CUDA, CUDNN and pip. To examine a graph I followed a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864363/tensorflow-how-to-convert-meta-data-and-index-model-files-into-one-graph-pb) which lead me to [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#inspecting-graphs), and accordingly I executed the command:

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
```

Script kiddie that I am.

Ten minutes later I looked back at it and Bazel is furiously compiling C files with paths that look suspiciously like a source code checkout.

Is it actually compiling TF from source?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes, that is indeed what the `bazel build` command does.

If you look at the actual BUILD file (*tensorflow/tools/graph_transform/BUILD*) you'll see that it has its build rules and dependencies, which basically includes all the source code in that directory. The `summarize_graph` command's logic is included in those (you'll find that in ***summarize_graph_main.cc*** under the same directory).

You can follow the specific build rule to see what it does, or use a visualization tool. Here's what it looks like:

```
tf_cc_binary(
    name = "summarize_graph",
    copts = tf_copts(),
    linkstatic = 1,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        ":summarize_graph_main_lib",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mat. I never heard of Bazel until I started messing with TF. Were it a make system or cmake system I'd have known what I was looking at.

Comment: Yeah I'm still a beginner at it too tbh, but having compiled TF a few times forced me to learn it a bit. Also btw you might want to take a look at the Python API to run such commands, you could avoid building the sources depending on what is supported etc.