# Convert data-00000-of-00001 file to Tensorflow Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is there any way to `convert data-00000-of-00001` to Tensorflow Lite model?
The file structure is like this

```
 |-semantic_model.data-00000-of-00001
 |-semantic_model.index
 |-semantic_model.meta
```

Comment: What tensorflow version have u used to save model to these files?

Comment: I downloaded this ML data from this site (https://towardsdatascience.com/i-built-a-music-sheet-transcriber-heres-how-74708fe7c04c)

Answer (score 1):

***Using TensorFlow Version: 1.15***

The following 2 steps will convert it to a `.tflite` model.

**1. Generate a TensorFlow Model for Inference (a frozen graph `.pb` file) using the [answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868106/3903505)**

What you currently have is model `checkpoint` (a TensorFlow 1 model saved in 3 files: .data..., .meta and .index. This model can be further trained if needed). You need to convert this to a `frozen graph` (a TensorFlow 1 model saved in a single `.pb` file. This model cannot be trained further and is optimized for inference/prediction).

**2. Generate a TensorFlow lite model ( `.tflite` file)**

A. Initialize the TFLiteConverter: The `.from_frozen_graph` API can be defined [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_frozen_graph) way and the attributes which can be added are [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#attributes). To find the names of these arrays, visualize the `.pb` file in [Netron](https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/)

```
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
    graph_def_file='....path/to/frozen_graph.pb', 
    input_arrays=...,
    output_arrays=....,
    input_shapes={'...' : [_, _,....]}
)
```

B. Optional: Perform the simplest optimization known as [post-training dynamic range quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#dynamic_range_quantization). You can refer to the same document for other types of optimizations/quantization methods.

```
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
```

C. Convert it to a `.tflite` file and save it

```
tflite_model = converter.convert()

tflite_model_size = open('model.tflite', 'wb').write(tflite_model)
print('TFLite Model is %d bytes' % tflite_model_size)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm stuck with Step 2. How can I convert frozen graph to tflite?

Comment: I've updated the code above. You need to use `tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph` in TF 1.x and `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph` in TF 2.x to load frozen graphs into the TFLiteConverter. Does this work for you? Could you post more details regarding the issue you're facing?