# How to convert .meta, .data and .index ckpt files to tf-serving support format?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-serving

I have trained a model where I got the checkpoints as below

[image: checkpoint files in export dir]

How do I convert these ckpt files to tf-serving format as such.

[image: required format of files needed]

The model was trained with tensorflow==1.14.0

Comment: are you using tensorflow tensorflow object detection api?

Comment: No @Zrufy I'm Training an EAST Text Detection model.

Comment: try tu use the code in object detection api "export_inference_graph.py" this one is used to convert these file in model to use.Check you are using the tensorflow object detection api equal to your 1.14.0.Let me know.

Comment: @explr_1298, This Stack Overflow Answer by velikodniy, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868106/11530462 should help you.